# How to allow OCSP but disallow all other outgoing HTTP requests?

Tags: arch-linux, iptables, proxy, http, squid

Is it possible to allow OCSP requests using for example iptables or Squid? I'm doing an experiment where I [reject insecure outgoing HTTP requests](https://l0b0.wordpress.com/2017/02/25/the-https-only-experience/), but OCSP is of course a valid exception since [the response is validated by the browser](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/72573/1220). Or is there at least some way to identify OCSP HTTP requests uniquely so as to write a custom filter for it?

Alternatively, is there an official list of IPs/subnets that are used for OCSP? [This](https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js/issues/73#issuecomment-154110933) looks promising, since [the author is forcing HTTPS](https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js/issues/73#issuecomment-154274082) in a different way, but there's no guarantee of it being maintained.

Answer (score 2):

This is *probably* beyond `iptables`; you're asking for filtering at the application layer which is pretty complex. I think you're going to have to look into `squid` paired with `iptables` that forces all `http` to go thru it.

*Edit*: Please see [question history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/349203/revisions) before downvoting; the original question has been updated with the content of this answer.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but I think Squid is a bit too much work to set up.